# Not allowed to load local resource (image) in MVC from wwwroot folder

Tags: image, asp.net-core, view, asp.net-core-mvc, resources

I tried to load images from `wwwroot` folder in ASP.NET Core MVC.
But in the Chrome when run view give me this error:

[image: not allowed to load resource]

There is my view code:

```
<img class="logo-logIn my-4" src="C:\Users\nwara\Source\Repos\HarbiMaimunah\MaintoSystem\BeneficiaryPortal\wwwroot\images\logo.png" alt="minto logo">
```

I tried to change the path and this give me `404 error` this the only path change the error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<img class="logo-logIn my-4" src="~\images\logo.png">
```

For detailed information see: [Image Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/image-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0)